# Dynamically adding data to listView which does not overwrite the previous data and permanently saving it

Tags: android, listview

In the following program, When I click on Add button in the options menu a dialog is opened wherein the user enters the data which is then shown in the ListView.
There are a number of problems with his code.

1) age.setText in the Custom Adapter causes the app to crash.Commenting out the age.settext line, it works well for the other two TextViews.

2) When i add data in the list using the dialog the second time, the list gets overwritten and no updation is done. 
I want the list to be automatically updated when new data is entered rather than over writing it.

3) The data vanishes away when i restart the app. I want the data to be saved permanently.

Code for Custom Adapter is:

```
package com.example.sakshi.dialogsandmenus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Data> list;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list){
    this.context=context;
    this.list=list;
    mLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView age = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.agedata);
    TextView dob = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dob);
    name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    //age.setText(list.get(position).getAge());
    dob.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Code for Main Activity is:

```
package com.example.sakshi.dialogsandmenus;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static android.R.id.list;
import static com.example.sakshi.dialogsandmenus.R.id.date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<Data> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id= item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.add){

        filldialog();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void filldialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.show();
    Button add = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.additem);
    final EditText getnamedata = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText getagedata = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)dialog.findViewById(date);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getname =  getnamedata.getText().toString();
            int getage = Integer.parseInt(getagedata.getText().toString());
            int mm,y,d;
            mm=datePicker.getMonth();
            y=datePicker.getYear();
            d=datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            String getdate = d+"/"+mm+"/"+y;
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            Data data = new Data();
            data.setName(getname);
            data.setAge(getage);
            data.setDate(getdate);
            arrayList.add(data);


            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);
            listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            //customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: 1. You'll probably getting a `NullPointerException`. Post the stack trace. 2. You're "resetting" your old adapter with a new one. That's why you are getting "ovewritten" data

Comment: You have to create `arrayList` as global variable. Currently each and every time while adding you creating as new list so the old list is overridden

Comment: For 3rd one you need to use Server side storage or Local storage like sqLite to store the data

Comment: Not global variable but attribute. Or add a method inside your adapter that allows you to add new data. 3. If you want to persist data consider using [Realm](https://realm.io/) or check [some documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) about it

Comment: using arraylist as the global variable works perfectly fine. Can you explain a bit more about how to store data permanently? @NaveenKumarM

Comment: Can you also explain as of why setText causes the app to crash? @NaveenKumarM

Comment: and you too @Pelocho

Comment: Using global variables is dangerous so you should avoid it. If your view lacks a `TextView` with id `agedata` your `findViewById` will return null and voilá, `NullPointerException`. Post your stacktrace and we will be able to say more

Comment: You can store data permanently in several ways. Just do some research and choose the one that fits you best. Be aware that you may need to **synchronize** data instead of just **caching** it

Comment: @thebrightshadow I added answer for why setText causes the app to crash? please check it. and For data storage you need to learn from various tutorials in one shot we can't solve your problem, It is a more detailed implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you have to convert the value of age to String before setText
//age.setText(list.get(position).getAge());

age.setText(Integer.toString(list.get(position).getAge()));

2) Every time new Arraylist initilaization 
 intarrayList = new ArrayList<>();

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public void filldialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.show();
    Button add = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.additem);
    final EditText getnamedata = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText getagedata = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)dialog.findViewById(date);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getname =  getnamedata.getText().toString();
            int getage = Integer.parseInt(getagedata.getText().toString());
            int mm,y,d;
            mm=datePicker.getMonth();
            y=datePicker.getYear();
            d=datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            String getdate = d+"/"+mm+"/"+y;

            Data data = new Data();
            data.setName(getname);
            data.setAge(getage);
            data.setDate(getdate);
            arrayList.add(data);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

enter code here

3) Use Sqlite or anyStorage Option for data saving

Answer (score 0):

You are setting int value directly to setText of ageTextView. You need to convert int to String before you setting a text to TextView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView age = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.agedata);
    TextView dob = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dob);
    name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    //age.setText(list.get(position).getAge());
    age.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getAge())); // use this it will work
    dob.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move these lines outside the onClickListener

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);
listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Because whenever you are clicking the button arraylist is initializing again.